# viewpager2: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the adapter to be 'fresh' while restoring state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

Here is the more of stacktrace

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the adapter to be 'fresh' while restoring state.
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStateAdapter.java:557)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.restorePendingState(ViewPager2.java:349)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.setAdapter(ViewPager2.java:462)
        at com.example.HomeFragmentContainer.onResume(HomeFragmentContainer.kt:76)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2747)
```

I think it's the same problem as [Expected the adapter to be 'fresh' while restoring state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56646711/expected-the-adapter-to-be-fresh-while-restoring-state%20FragmentStateAdapter)

HomPagerAdaptor

```kotlin
class HomPagerAdaptor(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    override fun getItemCount() = 2;
    override fun createFragment(position: Int) = when (position) {
        0 -> TimelineContainer()
        else -> HomeFragment()
    }
}
```

I'm using adaptor as

```kotlin
class HomeFragmentContainer : DaggerFragment() {

    private val adapter by lazy {  HomPagerAdaptor(this) }
...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding!!.vpContainer.adapter = adapter
    }
...
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        binding?.vpContainer?.adapter = null
        binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}
```

library versions:

```kotlin
 androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-alpha01
 androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha03
```

I did little bit of digging and found that when I set adaptor to null the underlying recyclerview's views are recycled and the adaptor trie to remove fragments by calling `removeFragment()`

```java
private void removeFragment(long itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = mFragments.get(itemId);

    ...
    if (shouldDelayFragmentTransactions()) {
          mHasStaleFragments = true;
          return;
     }
     try {
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commitNow();
            mFragments.remove(itemId);
        } finally {
            mFragmentEventDispatcher.dispatchPostEvents(onPost);
        }
}

  boolean shouldDelayFragmentTransactions() {
        return mFragmentManager.isStateSaved();
    }

// in FragmentManager
   public boolean isStateSaved() {
        // See saveAllState() for the explanation of this.  We do this for
        // all platform versions, to keep our behavior more consistent between
        // them.
        return mStateSaved || mStopped;
    }
```

But the `shouldDelayFragmentTransactions()` returns true because the fragment is already stopped and the fragments are not removed from adaptor. Later when the fragment pops back and sets the adapter in `onViewCreated()` the adaptor tries to restore state, but before doing that, it checks if there are any stale fragments in adaptor as

```java
  @Override
    public final void restoreState(@NonNull Parcelable savedState) {
        if (!mSavedStates.isEmpty() || !mFragments.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Expected the adapter to be 'fresh' while restoring state.");
        }
```

It fixes the problem when I set adaptor to null in `onResume()` or `onStop()` but the viewpager's state is not restored later and defeats the whole purpose of using FragmentStateAdapter.

Edit: added more info

Comment: You'll need to create new `HomPagerAdaptor(this)` every time it's assigned to `vpContainer.adapter`.