# ViewPager2 reuse fragments when popbackstack is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I have main fragment with `ViewPager2` that contains other fragments.
Each child fragment can open another detail fragment (main fragment replaced with details fragment).
When I go back to from detail fragment, `ViewPager2` recreate all child fragments.

If I try to reuse the adapter (`FragmentStateAdapter`):

```
if (pagerAdapter == null) {
        pagerAdapter = Adapter(this)
        binding.viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    }else{
        binding.viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    }
```

I got crash:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
> at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView(FragmentStateAdapter.java:132)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapterInternal(RecyclerView.java:1209)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(RecyclerView.java:1161)
> at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.setAdapter(ViewPager2.java:461)

How to avoid creating new fragment every time?

Comment: I have some problem

Comment: Check for this link -[https://stackoverflow.com/a/74920682/1216186]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I init adapter every time in onCreate, before I used lazy for init adapter.

logVP2.adapter = SummaryDetailsPageAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle).apply {
setData(args?.list)
}

Comment: this should be marked as the right answer. but why this happen really? what is the problem with lazy?